# sync sound on multiple computers

Tags: wireless, sound, sync

I recently acquired two computers because the university bought new ones. I connected them to my two sound system (I managed to acquire two old sound systems some time ago) using a jack 3.5 output. I've put them on opposite sides of my room (yes it's just the one room) and I would like to sync the sound output of both pc's using wifi.

Normally I would just use vlc, correct for the delay and be done with it but unfortunately I'm not streaming mp3 files but actual sound from the internet.

I do not care if there is a delay between receiving the sound and actual playing the sound I just want these two pc's sound systems synced.

The distance between the two computers and sound systems is to long to be able to cheaply run a jack cable between them without sound quality loss.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not have 2 PCs readily available, I'm not sure that this works. But by experimenting around this solution you should be able to get it to work.

Let's say you want to work from PC1 and play sounds on both PC1 and PC2.

---

**On both PC1 and PC2:**

Install PulseAudio Preferences:

```
sudo apt-get install paprefs
```

**On PC1 only:**

1. Open PulseAusio Preferences dialog (from Dash, say).
2. In the `Network Access` tab enable `Make discoverable PulseAudio network...`. This will make the sound device in PC2 accessible from PC1, if allowed by PC2.

**On PC2 only:**

1. Open PulseAusio Preferences dialog.
2. In the `Network Server` tab check `Enable network access to local sound devices` and `Allow other machines on LAN to discover local sound devices`. This makes the sound device in PC2 visible to PC1.
3. Do not check `Don't require authentication` - that will allow others on the LAN to spam your sound system.

**Providing authentication:**

Copy `~/.pulse-cookie` file from one of the PCs to the other, so that that file is identical in both PCs. It doesn't matter which PC's file is copied to the other.

---

At this point (possibly after rebooting the two PCs), you should be able to play sounds from PC1 on PC2's sound system:

**On PC1**

1. Open the volume control dialog.
2. In the `Output` tab change to PC2's sound device (Under the list "Play sound through").
3. Play some sample audio in PC1 and verify that you can hear the output in PC2.

---

Now you want the sound server on PC1 to forward sounds to both sound devices (available locally to it). For this you have to create a virtual sound device whose slaves are the two available devices. An easy of doing this is

**On PC1:**

1. Open PulseAudio Preferences dialog.
2. In the `Simultaneous Output` tab, enable `Add virtual...`.
3. From the volume control dialog, choose this virtual output device.

---

Notes:

1. Simultaneous output on *all* local sound cards may not be desirable, in which case you should take a look at `pacmd`'s `module-combine` option to combine only select sinks.
2. If you wish to work from either PC1 or PC2 and want all sounds to play on both PCs, perform PC1 and PC2 specific steps on both PC1 and PC2.
3. Hopefully the network is strong enough that no noticeable sync errors will creep in. If not, apparently one will have to modify some buffer sizes to set things right.

Sources:

1. http://blog.nekoconeko.nl/blog/2012/03/03/PulseAudio-over-network.html
2. http://psung.blogspot.in/2011/09/network-audio-with-pulseaudio-made.html

Comment: thanks. It didn't work at first but by fiddling around with PulseAudio Preferences I got it to work. Now I only need to get the synchronization correct but I'm sure I should be able to do that.

Comment: Just curious. Was it the settings in Multicast/RTP tab (instead of Simultaneous Output tab) that got it working?

Comment: I had to set a delay of a wopping 400 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two systems are in the same room, and assuming playing the same audio track.Is it possible for you to just run long cables from one computer? So you can take one computer and attach a 3.5 jack splitter (if there is only one) attach one set of speakers to one of the outputs and the other set of speakers to the second output (you should be able to find 3.5jack extension cables if the one provided is not long enough). Or is the key to this set up to be strictly wireless?

Comment: Well, I would like to do it for free and since I have a rather big room the jack cable would have to be rather long.
Besides if you use a really long jack cable the sound gets distorted more easily. You'll need a really high grade cable or amplifiers to compensate for the length of the cable.
I recon the cable will have to be about 8 to 10 meters long (26 to 32 ft) unless I want to run the cable straight though the center of the room which is a bit, well, ugly.