# How can I synchronize the volume between two laptops?

Tags: internet, volume-control

I have two laptops on my desktop. They are both connected to the LAN, one via wireless and one via Ethernet.

When I turn the volume up on one laptop, I'd like it to turn it up on the other.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this automatically, so I'll give you a few ideas that might get you closer. You could look into using something like Synergy (http://symless.com/download-synergy-for-free) to allow you to move the mouse between the 2 laptops seemlessly so you wouldn't have to switch computers to get them back in  sync, you'd just use one of the laptop's mice and cursor would move over to the other laptop.

Alternatively, if you really need them to be completely sync'd, you will probably have to write some custom code to communicate. I haven't used it personally, but [sync sound on multiple computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379024/sync-sound-on-multiple-computers) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Synergy is why I want to do this :-) I keep adjusting sound on the wrong machine!